# Why no client-side HTML include tag?

Tags: history, html

I had a question posed to me the other day by another programmer.  I remember (a very long time ago) wondering the very same.  **Why was a browser-side include tag never considered?  Or was it?**

Specifically with a tag that instructed the browser to include additional HTML from other sources. e.g. `<include src="http://server/foo/bar.html">`.  Many folks will make javascript calls and fill `innerHTML` to accomplish the same, when the same outside a the javascript engine could be accomplished by the browser.

It would have been painful to have nested `<HTML>`s `<BODY>`s (i.e.) but we have to consider that aspect anywhere anyway.

Comment: Don't external entities give you this already?

Comment: Transclusion was considered a core feature of hypertext even from its invention in the 60s. So I'm sure it was *considered*...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Am I the last person on earth who remembers the ([Netscape 4-only](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_element)) [`layer`](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/tagpages/l/layer.htm) and [`ilayer`](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/tagpages/i/ilayer.htm) tags?

[Netscape 4 also allowed](http://developer.mozilla.org/index.php?title=en/Using_Web_Standards_in_your_Web_Pages&revision=8) the `div` tag to have a `src` attribute, which accomplished the same thing.

Netscape submitted them to the W3C, who chose to not include them—use `iframe` instead.

Comment: I indeed remember NS4 but do not remember those features.  Too bad, I still content it would save a lot of cross-browser javascript BS.

Comment: I remember hating NS4 with such a passion that one of my first non-ISP email address was a free account at ihatenetscape.com. Ah, good times :D

Comment: Note layers weren't quite a client side include as they still had a separate `document` object subject to Same Origin Policy; they were effectively a positionable iframe.

Comment: too sad, it's already 2020 and the 'src' attribute on 'div' tag is still not added. What is W3C doing?

Answer (score 15):

> Why was a browser-side include tag never considered? Or was it?

It was certainly requested by every newbie web author who hadn't worked out Server Side Includes yet, back in the early days on the www-html list. But in those days W3 were happy to completely ignore web author pressure.

If cross-site inclusion were allowed it would be a security disaster. You could pull in a page from the user's bank and read content from it. (Originally, DOM scripting was limited, but you could still have read from `document.links`, `document.images`, scripting functions dropped by the target page, etc. Since then you can do what you like with imported content.)

If cross-site inclusion weren't allowed... well then the feature wouldn't have any advantage over server-side includes. It'd be more, slower work for the client to do that the server could have dealt with better. Unlike `<iframe>`, an include would have to block page loading. SSIs would be in every way superior.

Comment: Actually, the client (or a proxy) could cache more efficiently, as templates (or header/footer includes) don't tend to change from page to page, meaning the user might at least be able to see part of the page whilst some server-side processing is going on.

Comment: It would do significantly more than the server.  I'm not sure why it would need to block page load, it could have allowed for full page load with async content-fill.  Of course it could be limited by browsers to only allow pull from originating servers or to allow a domained DOM.

Comment: I don't get how it is a security disaster. I can read a bank page on server side right now and spit it out on another page - is it a disaster? Maybe, but certainly not security related one. Security disaster would be reading cookies from a different domain. Without this client side include would be exactly the same as server side one. Don't see any problem here.

Comment: You can try to fetch a bank page on the server side but your request will be unauthenticated so you can't download any juicy information. A request from the client side includes cookies and HTTP authentication tokens; if you can read the response from such a request you can fully impersonate the user.

Comment: @bobince: Is there any reason that the request on the client side would have to include cookies and HTTP authentication tokens?  The primary usage scenario I would see for client-side includes would be to improve caching of static page content.  If sixteen pages all include the same header and footer, using a client-side include would increase the time required to load the first, but reduce the time to load the remaining fifteen.  The usage cases where the include would be the most helpful would be precisely those where the data to be "included" would be static and thus not need...

Comment: ...access to cookies and authentication tokens (even if a site used cookies to select among different "skins", one could simply have the generated HTML for the site vary the path to the included file based upon the chosen skin.  The first page loaded after changing skins would have to fetch a new include file for that skin, but later pages could use the new cached one; the earlier skin would remain in the cache, and would appear if any pages that haven't been revisited since the skin change are viewed in "off-line" mode.

Comment: @supercat: there are other forms of authentication, such as connection-level (HTTPS client certs and IWA) and location-based (eg pages on an intranet which you can access from your browser in a secure network - don't want that to leak to the outside). Adding ‘unauthenticated’ HTTP connections to browsers is tricky—just look at the problems Java applets and Flash caused by doing something similar with their own network stacks.

Comment: @bobince: If an HTML-include request could forbid the included HTML from including any nested resources which weren't white-listed by the include request itself, and applied a prefix to the ID attribute of all included items, how would it be any worse than `<img>` or (dare I say it) JavaScript?

Comment: Nested resources aren't a problem. Client side request forgery is the problem. Putting includes in the parent DOM is worse than an `<img>` because you can't read the content of an `<img>`. (You *can* find out whether the target resource is a valid image and if so how big it is, and there was a worse attack with stylesheet inclusion which the browsers have largely worked around; these are bad things, which partially break the Same Origin Policy and wouldn't have been allowed by default if we'd had CORS at the time. But nothing like as bad as reading the entire content of the target via DOM.)

Comment: @bobince: As I would want it implemented, an attempt to include any resource from a server which didn't respond to a request "Page XX wants to include resource YY" with "Here's resource YY, which I want to make availabe to page XX" would be blocked by the browser.  If the server explicitly wants to make something available for client-side includes, I don't see how that should cause problems with client-side request forging if servers don't accept include requests for content which shouldn't be freely available.

Answer (score 11):

They did. It became the `<frameset>` tag. Not long after, they added the `<iframe>` tag.

Most of the early web servers supported server-side includes, so a client-side textual include was likely thought to be unnecessary, given that the same functionality was available also with frames.

Comment: Not really frames serve a very different purpose than inclusion.  Plus the restrictions on iframes especially in object set size surely could not have thought to take its place.

Comment: I disagree - I think that's exactly what frames do.  What else are frames for except including more HTML?

Comment: Frames are including HTML in frames, not directly -- this is the difference.

Comment: @Jaco, frames are a rough windowing layout of HTML.  Nothing to do with document inclusion.  How do you include HTML parts without JavaScript inline in a document with a frame or without a scroll window?

Comment: @Xepoch: ... With an `<iframe>`. That's what it's *for*. It's really not much different from a `<div>` with `overflow:auto;`

Comment: Yes that's exactly what an iFrame is for.

Comment: @jaco, please explain how iframe simulates anything that a client-include would do?  Who chooses an iframe instead of ajax for instance?  This makes no sense to me.

Comment: The <iframe> element basically says "load the specified html document and stick it here".  You would choose it instead of ajax if you want the document to be loaded immediately, not on a javascript call...  Frames are NOT windowing layout of HTML.  Div, p, br - these are all elements used for layout.  You don't use frames for layout (or you shouldn't anyways).

Comment: Also, look into the `seamless` attribute that HTML5 adds to the `iframe` tag, it makes it even more effective at including additional HTML directly into the structure of your page.

Comment: navigation must be consistent from page to page.  You cannot float a navigation menu in an iframe unless you make the iframe cover everything below which mean you will not be able to click on links below the iframe.  At this point EVERYONE knows the difference between iframe and includes.  They have very different use case.

Answer (score 4):

Object still renders in a frame and you have no DOM access to "data." What developers should have been given years ago is a way to include snippets with a simple tag. Even if this tag had domain sandbox restrictions it would be pretty useful to compartmentalize features, improve maintenance and take advantage of browser caching.

I know there are plenty of good jquery plugins that do this and lots of server side scripts, but there is no good reason to not support such a tag. IMO its a good question "Why no client-side include tag?"

If you like jquery here is a good client side include script: [inc: A super-tiny client-side include JavaScript jQuery plugin](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/inc-a-super-tiny-client-side-include-javascript-jquery-plugin.html)

Comment: Your reply is the only one that seems to have hit the nail on the head.  Are you thinking of something like #include in C?  This is exactly the kind of thing "client-side include" means to me - a facility for including arbitrary HTML snippets (rather than entire HTML documents) within an HTML document as integral document content.  Though it could be designed as an integral feature of HTML rather than as a pre-parsing stage - the asker's suggested <include src="..."> syntax would fit right in with this.

Comment: The problem with adding it now would be backward compatibility.  Of course, this doesn't explain why it wasn't included in the original design of HTML.

Comment: It could alternatively have been designed as a feature of SGML/XML more generally....

Comment: even the javascript solutions require a server.  We need a solution that does not require a server.  Why does this not exist yet?  It just makes extra work for developers.  Just give us html snipit injection without need for server. Everybody wants it.

Answer (score 4):

Variants on an `<include>` tag were indeed considered in [the early history of HTML](http://diveintohtml5.org/past.html), but they never got very far.

Comment: However the semantics of that <include> tag were similar to those of today's frame/iframe/object - it would include a html *document*, and not just snippets of text/code or random tags as C's #include would.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried

```
<object  type="text/html" data="page.html" height="500" width="500">
What I see if that didn't work 
</object>
```

I think that's implemented in most browsers.

Comment: Will need to try.

Comment: interesting, but the contents inside 'page.html' are isolated (iframe), can't access anything outside